# How to Crop the image in specific size programmatically in android

Tags: android

I'm trying to crop the image using the bitmap creation method. But I unable to get the exact result from Google Pixel mobile. Please help me out, how do I achieve this? For your reference, I have mentioned my code below.

Thanks in advance.

```
private void cropCapturedImage(File mFile) {
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> {
        Bitmap capturedImagebitmap, rotatedBitmap;
        capturedImagebitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mFile.getPath());
        final BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bitmapOptions.inTargetDensity = 1;
        capturedImagebitmap.setDensity(Bitmap.DENSITY_NONE);

        int height = (int) (capturedImagebitmap.getHeight() * 0.17);
        int y = (int)(capturedImagebitmap.getHeight() * 0.35);
        Log.e("Camera",">>"+height+">>"+y);
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(capturedImagebitmap, 0, y, capturedImagebitmap.getWidth(), height);});
}
```

[image]

Comment: What dimensions are you attempting to resize the image to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missed to rotate the image. Now I have rotated the image, image crop working fine. Below I have mentioned the working code.

```
try {
ei = new ExifInterface(mFile.getAbsolutePath());

int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);


switch (orientation) {

case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(capturedImagebitmap, 90);
break;

case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(capturedImagebitmap, 180);
break;

case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(capturedImagebitmap, 270);
break;

case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
rotatedBitmap = capturedImagebitmap;
break;

default:
rotatedBitmap = capturedImagebitmap;

}
// cropping image
int height = (int) (rotatedBitmap.getHeight() * 0.2);
int y = (int) (rotatedBitmap.getHeight() * 0.4);

Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(rotatedBitmap, 0, y, rotatedBitmap.getWidth(), height);

savebitmap(resizedBitmap);

showPreviewImage();

} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
public static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap source, float angle) {
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(angle);
return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(),
matrix, true);
}
```